# Seeking appropriate distribution for continuous 0-1 bound bimodal response variable in glmms

Tags: generalized-linear-model, glmm

I am seeking assistance on choosing appropriate distribution for glmms. My response variable is continuous, positive & bimodal with values ranged from 0-1.  I have attached histogram here. Thank you for any assistance[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with the parameters $\alpha < 1.0$ and $\beta < 1.0$

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am familiar with glmmtmb package in R.  I just looked it up. They haven't specified alpha < 1.0 and beta < 1.0, as you've done. They have specified beta distribution as family=beta_family(link="logit") and family = beta_family(). Would it work if I choose one of two options? Thanks again.

Comment: I didn't work with this package, but `link="logit"` is apparently wrong.